# Can a C++ static template function be in a struct with C linkage?

Tags: c++, class, templates, static, linkage

I have the following declaration in my header file:

```
extern "C" {
    struct lfModifier {
        template<typename T>
        static void ModifyColor_Vignetting_PA (
           void *data, float x, float y, T *rgb, int comp_role, int count);
    }
}
```

GCC probably rightfully complains "error: template with C linkage".  But the template is static after all.  I could easily move it out of the class into the cpp file.  I don't like to do that because having it in the struct increases code readability.

Is there a way to have a static template in this context?

Comment: even if this is possible there's no practical use for it

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by having a **member** function with C linkage? No other `extern C` member function of other class being able to share the same name?

Comment: @Mondkin: It is about a library in C++.  I think (I maintain code of somebody else) the goal is to use the same library header file for C and C++ programs.  The C programs see `struct` and attributes, and the C++ programs see everything but with C linkage.  Well, and then, the template member fails.

Comment: You can't have this inside the header file anyway, since C doesn't know what a template is.  And if you hide it from C using `#define`, you break the One Definition Rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It is hidden from C with `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Comment: @TorstenBronger: Then the type is different in C and in C++, but you are giving them the same name (with the same linkage) and (says the Standard) that is undefined behavior.  You can try to rely on standard-layout rules to make the data members line up and create two layout-compatible types, but then they are still separate types which require separate names.

Comment: @BenVoigt, this may be true, however, this is another issue, which requires in-depth analysis that we cannot do in SO comments.  My code above is heavily simplified of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you need other members in the struct to have C linkage, the template function can have C++ linkage.

```
extern "C" {
    struct lfModifier {
        int val;
        void foo();

        extern "C++" template<typename T>
        static void ModifyColor_Vignetting_PA (
           void *data, float x, float y, T *rgb, int comp_role, int count);
    }
}
```

`extern C++` for a member of a struct will override the `extern C` attribute of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Inside header
extern "C" { struct X; };
struct X {
    template <typename T> static void f() {}
};

// Inside cpp
int main() {
    X::f<int>();
}
```

Comment: while this codeblock might answer the question, please try to add relevant explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

Check this other question and its answer:
[In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

The most important parts from there:

- extern "C" is ignored for class members
- at most one function with a particular name can have "C" linkage (regardless of namespace)
- 'static' inside 'extern "C"' is valid; an entity so declared has internal linkage, and so does not have a language linkage

The most important there is the one in the middle: when you instantiate your template you would have two functions with the same name, but different parameters, which is not directly supported by C. So the C++ compiler needs to mangle the name for templated functions.

Also, when you declare your function outside the struct and you say it is `static` you are giving it internal linkage, so the `extern C` will be ignored (that's the reason why it compiles in that case). Have you used `objdump` to see the compiled name to make sure it is not being mangled?